# trying to display message to user after prompts and between for loop

Tags: javascript

```
var a = prompt("Input for smallest account:");

var b = prompt("Input for largest account:");

var inca = prompt("Increment for account a:");

var incb = prompt("Increment for account b:");

var num1 = parseInt(a);

var num2 = parseInt(b);

var num3 = parseInt(inca);

var num4 = parseInt(incb);


for (var i = 1; num1 !== num2; i ++) {

num1 += num3;

num2 += num4;

document.write("Day: " + i, "   Account A: " + num1, "   Account B: " + num2, "<br>");
}
```

How would I display a message to user saying accounts won’t be equal if `num4` is greater than `num3` and therefore will not run the `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

This is basic javascript. I'd even say, basic programming:

```
if (num4 > num3) {
  alert('your-error-message-here');
} else for (var i = 1; num1 !== num2; i ++) {
  num1 += num3;
  num2 += num4;
  document.write("Day: " + i, "   Account A: " + num1, "   Account B: " + num2, "<br>");
}
```

Comment: thank you, i did try something very similar but must have had a small error in it somewhere.
i am new to programming